# hbase, phoenix - upserting 'value' to existing null column doesn't works on some records

Tags: hbase, upsert, apache-phoenix

I'm facing with a very weird behaviour with an UPSERT instruction: the operation doesn't have effect on columns that was previously stored with null value;

for example, if we have 'tab1'

```
create table IF NOT EXISTS tab1(id VARCHAR not null, eventdate TIMESTAMP not null, category VARCHAR, history VARBINARY);
UPSERT into tab1(id,eventdate,category,history) values ('id1',to_timestamp('2022-10-20 00:00:00.0','test',null);
```

and the upsert query is

```
UPSERT into tab1(id,eventdate,category,history) values ('id1',to_timestamp('2022-10-20 00:00:00.0','edited test','ABC');
```

the result of a select on tab1 is:

```
+-----+-----------------------+-------------+---------+
| id  |        eventdate      |  category   | history |
+-----+-----------------------+-------------+---------+
| id1 | 2022-10-20 00:00:00.0 | edited test |         |
+-----+-----------------------+-------------+---------+
```

the 'history' column doesn't change... I verified that this happens only for some records... so I can't figure out why it happens and how to solve...

Did someone has some clue on this ???

thank you all